# Remove class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

I want to remove class "ndfHFb-c4YZDc-aSZUA-Wrql6b" from div (to hide some toolbar)[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Rphk.jpg)

```
<div class="ndfHFb-c4YZDc-aSZUA-Wrql6b" role="toolbar" style="width: 226px; right: 12px; opacity: 1;"><div class="ndfHFb-c4YZDc-aSZUA-Wrql6b-AeOLfc-b0t70b"><div class="ndfHFb-c4YZDc-nJjxad-nK2kY......
```

i try to do it simple with

```
$('.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-aSZUA-Wrql6b').remove();
$('div.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-aSZUA-Wrql6b').remove();
```

but it dont work. Thanks in advance

Comment: The `remove` method will remove the element from the DOM. If you want to remove class, you have to call `removeClass`. For example: `$('.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-aSZUA-Wrql6b').removeClass('ndfHFb-c4YZDc-aSZUA-Wrql6b');`.

Comment: seems that it is inside an `<iframe>`, check this link out: [changing elements from iframes jquery](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/changing-elements-in-an-iframe)

Comment: dont work for me, can you see the image in attachment there is more code of that page...

Comment: Santiago, yes it is in an iframe i will try something from your link

Comment: IMHO, if you're using the presence of the class to flag its visibility, and that class is the only thing distinguishing that element from any other, then you're doing it wrong, since you just destroyed the very thing that'll let you reinstate the element later...

Comment: Hi, did you get it to work? I cannot hide the toolbar..

Answer (score 1):

You were really close.

```
$('div.ndfHFb-c4YZDc-aSZUA-Wrql6b').removeClass('ndfHFb-c4YZDc-aSZUA-Wrql6b');
```

is the correct solution. Make sure not to include the class' `.` when using `removeClass`.

I'd encourage you to rename the class to something more human readable.

Also, as Donte suggested, it would be best if you gave the `div` an id to allow you to target it consistently.

Comment: dont work, maybe i need to include id of iframe... because class is in iframe

Comment: You can't apply any CSS or JS to stuff in an iframe. An iframe is essentially an embed of a completely different site. You can't mess with it's HTML structure. :(

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would set an id to the div and then target the id in jquery... Then remove the Class.

```
if($("div[role='toolbar']").length){
  $("div[role='toolbar']").removeClass('ndfHFb-c4YZDc-aSZUA-Wrql6b');
}
```

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/g0srar72/2/

Comment: i dont have id in DIV (its generated page by embed code)... Can you see image in attachment

Comment: @SantiagoHernández I know... He wants to remove the class. So if it's always true. It will always remove the class.

Comment: @SantiagoHernández It's called a sanity check. I don't want to run the code if there isn't any div with the role='toolbar' on screen anymore.

Comment: @SantiagoHernández Should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To remove class use removeClass

**EDITED**

```
if($('div[role="toolbar"]').hasClass("ndfHFb-c4YZDc-aSZUA-Wrql6b")){
    $('div[role="toolbar"]').removeClass("ndfHFb-c4YZDc-aSZUA-Wrql6b");
}
```

Refer [Link](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)

Explanation : Grab Div with role toolbar and check if it has class XYZ if yes remove the class from that div.

Comment: @boshermen Try now . I was in other domain ! :)

Comment: `this` will not refer to the div you want in this context

Comment: @devqon , Updated to target proper div

Comment: No you didn't. The `this` does not points to the context where the `if()` applies on

Comment: @SantiagoHernández , multitasking on multiple question makes me crazy . Edited.

Answer (score 0):

So as I've understood the problem comme from the fact that it is included in a `<iframe>`

In this case you can try something like :

`$('iframe').contents().find('[role="toolbar"]).removeClass('ndfHFb-c4YZDc-Wrql6b')`